# Make Axis line grey or reduce opacity

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I want to make the axis lines either less opaque, or make them light grey. I tried to just do .style(opacity, 0.5), but it only makes the TICKS opaque, not the actual line itself. I want to make the ACTUAL LINE less opaque/light grey. I also tried adding the call(d3.axisLeft...).style(less opaque) approach but I still get nothing. How do I go about doing that?[image]

```
import React, {Component, useRef, useEffect} from 'react';
import ExperienceScoresData from './experience_scores';
import * as d3 from "d3";
import { select, csv} from 'd3';
import { extent, max, min } from "d3-array";


ExperienceScoresData.map(function(val){
  val.customerExperienceScore *= 100;
  return 0;
})

class Linechart extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.createBarChart = this.createBarChart.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.createBarChart()
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.createBarChart()
  }

  createBarChart() {
    var margin = {top: 85, right: 60, bottom: 60, left: 80},
        width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var node = this.node
    var divObj = select(node)
    var svgObj = divObj
                  .append("svg")
                  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
                  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                  .append("g")
                  .attr("transform","translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
    //Read the data
    d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/QamarFarooq/data-for-testing/main/5_OneCatSevNumOrdered.csv", function(data) {

      // group the data: I want to draw one line per group
      var sumstat = d3.nest() // nest function allows to group the calculation per level of a factor
        .key(function(d) { return d.name;})
        .entries(data);
      //console.log(sumstat)

      // Define the div for the tooltip
      var tooltip = divObj
        .append("div")  
        .attr("class","tooltip")
        .style("position", "absolute")
        .style("z-index", "10")
        .style("visibility", "hidden")
        .style("background-color", "white")
        .style("border", "solid")
        .style("border-width", "1px")
        .style("border-radius", "5px")
        .style("padding", "10px")
        .text("I AM A TOOLTIP pakistan zindabad");    
   
      // Add title for linechart
      svgObj.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("font-size", 25)
        .attr("x", 110)
        .attr("y", -50)
        .text("Online Ratings");      

      // Add X axis --> it is a date format
      var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; }))
        .range([ 0, width ]);
      svgObj.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .attr("stroke-width","0.3")
        .style("opacity","0.5")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).tickSize(-height).tickFormat('').ticks(5));
      // ticks
      svgObj.append("g")
      .style("opacity","0.85")
        .style("font", "14px times")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(5));

      // Add Y axis  
      var y = d3.scaleLinear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.n; })])
        .range([ height, 0 ]);
      svgObj.append("g")
        .attr("stroke-width","0.3")
        .style("opacity","0.5")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).tickSize(-width).tickFormat('').ticks(5));
        
      // ticks
      svgObj.append("g")
      .style("opacity","0.85")
        .style("font", "14px times")
        .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5));

      // Add X axis label:
      svgObj.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("font-size", 20)
        .attr("x", width/2 + margin.left)
        .attr("y", height + 50)
        .style("fill", d3.color("grey"))
        .text("Year Of Birth");

      // Add Y axis label:
      svgObj.append("text")
        .attr("text-anchor", "end")
        .attr("font-size", 20)
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("x", -height/2 + 40)
        .attr("y", -margin.left + 25)
        .style("fill", d3.color("grey"))
        .text("N-Value")
        
      // color palette
      var key = sumstat.map(function(d){ return d.key }) // list of group names

      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(key)
        .range(['#e41a1c','#377eb8','#4daf4a'])

      // Add one DOT in the legend for each name.
      svgObj.selectAll(".dots")
        .data(key)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function(d,i){ return 250 + i*120})
          .attr("cy", -30) 
          .attr("r", 7)
          .style("fill", function(d){ return color(d)})

      // Add LABEL for legends of each dot.
      svgObj.selectAll(".labels")
        .data(key)
        .enter()
        .append("text")
          .style("fill", d3.color("grey"))
          .attr("x", function(d,i){ return 270 + i*120})
          .attr("y", -28) 
          .text(function(d){ return d})
          .attr("text-anchor", "left")
          .style("alignment-baseline", "middle")

      // Draw the line
      svgObj.selectAll(".line")
          .data(sumstat)
          .enter()
          .append("path")
            .attr("fill", "none")
            .attr("stroke", function(d){ return color(d.key) })
            .attr("stroke-width", 4.5)
            .attr("d", function(d){
              return d3.line()
                .curve(d3.curveMonotoneX)
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.year); })
                .y(function(d) { return y(+d.n); })
                (d.values)
            })
            .on("mouseover", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "visible");})
            .on("mousemove", function(){return tooltip.style("top", (d3.event.pageY-10)+"px").style("left",(d3.event.pageX+10)+"px");})
            .on("mouseout", function(){return tooltip.style("visibility", "hidden");})
      
      var dataUnpacked = sumstat.map( function(d){return d.values})
      console.log(data)
      
      // Draw dots on points
      svgObj.selectAll(".lineChartDots")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("circle")
              .attr("class","lineChartDots")
              .style("fill","white")
              .style("stroke-width", "3px")
              .style("stroke", function (d) { return color(d.name) })
              .attr("cx", function(d) {return x(d.year); })
              .attr("cy", function(d) {return y(d.n); })
              .attr("r", 5.5)
    })

    }
    render() {
      return <div ref={node => this.node = node} className="example_div"> </div>
   }
}

export default Linechart;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following could change the axis line's opacity.

```
svg.append("g")
    .style("opacity", 0.5)
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
    .call(g => { // manipulate the elements' attrs here
        g.select("path")
         .attr("opacity", 0.5)
    });
```

I run your code and found that the above code actually worked but since there are two svg lines in the axis, both the **axis path** and the first background **grid line**, so you might feel the opacity wasn't changed. See [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x1zh60ky/22/) here.

a simple demo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>

<!-- Create a div where the graph will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<script>

// set the dimensions and margins of the graph
var margin = {top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 60},
    width = 460 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

// append the svg object to the body of the page
var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
  .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

//Read the data
d3.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/data_to_viz/master/Example_dataset/3_TwoNumOrdered_comma.csv",

  // When reading the csv, I must format variables:
  function(d){
    return { date : d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d")(d.date), value : d.value }
  },

  // Now I can use this dataset:
  function(data) {

    // Add X axis --> it is a date format
    var x = d3.scaleTime()
      .domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }))
      .range([ 0, width ]);
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

    // Add Y axis
    var y = d3.scaleLinear()
      .domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return +d.value; })])
      .range([ height, 0 ]);
    svg.append("g")
      .style("opacity", 0.5)
      .call(d3.axisLeft(y))
      .call(g => {
          g.select("path")
           .attr("opacity", 0.5)
      });

    // Add the line
    svg.append("path")
      .datum(data)
      .attr("fill", "none")
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1.5)
      .attr("d", d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date) })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.value) })
        )

})

</script>
```